# QT Is a slot launched in a separate thread

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have done some research on this topic . the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260786/updating-gui-form-elements-continuously-so-that-form-does-not-hang) at SO also caught my interest and I wanted to summarize my understanding and be corrected if I am going wrong on a certain path and also wanted to know how QueuedConnection would work.

Here is my understanding followed by the question.
Signals can be connected manually to slots primarily through two different ways first way is using direct connection and the second way is  queued connection. In case of a direct connection if the slot method that is attached to the signal is in the same thread then the slot method is called sequentially (as if it was just another method) however incase the slot is in a different thread from where the signal is launched then QueuedConnection would launch it when it finds it appropriate. (Now In this case I am not sure if it would launch a new thread or how it would proceed on doing that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slots don't belong to any particular thread, as they are just plain functions. But objects do. If you connect a signal to a slot by `QueuedConnection`, the signal emission will create an event and send that into the event queue of the target. Qt will arrange that your slot will be called when internally processing that event.

As for all events, they are processed in the thread of the object's *thread affinity*. You can change that thread by calling `moveToThread` on the target object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation could you explain what you mean by objects thread affinity ?

Comment: The thread affinity of an object, very generally speaking, is just the thread its methods will run in (when called via the object's event dispatch). E.g. if you call `myObject.moveToThread(myThread)` then any method that gets called on that object *via signals/slots* will execute in `myThread`, NOT in the thread from which the event was generated. In this way, signals/slots can be used to have objects notify each other of things across "thread boundaries."

Comment: "from which the event was generated" - I'd avoid the term 'event' here, as it could be confused with Qt's event system, with which signal/slots have nothing to do.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that is not true. the slot is invoked by sending a `QEvent::MetaCall` event.

Comment: Right, that's true for queued connections indeed (and thus for multithreaded signal/slots).

Answer (score 1):

**In multithread environement when sender and recievr object is in diffrent thread.**

> Qt::QueuedConnection

- What is happening when emiting thread? it simply emits( internally
  postevent, to reciever threads message queue) and **resume emiter
  thread**( not blocking).
- what is happening on reciever thread, after executing above
  statement? The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop
  of the receiver's thread.

> Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection

- What is happening on emiting thread ? it  emits( internally sendEvent,
  to reciever message queue) and **block emiter thread** until receiver
  slot returnes.(Blocking).
- what happening on receiever thread ? The slot is invoked when control
  returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, for QueuedConnection Qt will make a queue of received signals for the thread the slot belongs to, and will launch them one by one in order they are stored in the queue when the thread becomes available (it finishes whatever it was doing and returns to event loop).

No new thread will be launched - slot belongs to some thread, so execution will be performed in that thread.