# Qt5 signal and slot are not in the thread

Tags: c++, qt

a class defines a signal and a slot,

```cpp
connect(this, &MyClass::signalToDoSomething, this, &MyClass::slotToDoSomething);
```

In the same class, it has a function `foo` that emit signal. But, `foo` and `slotToDoSomething` are not in the same thread. I read [slot launched in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261343/qt-is-a-slot-launched-in-a-separate-thread). One answer says `foo` and slot are not in the same objects, which are different threads too. Then I am confused, as in `connect` **both emitter and slot are bound to `this`, then why slot are called in a different object, why not the current (emitter's) object**?

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    : MyBase(nullptr)
{
    _InitializeConnect();
}
void MyClass::_InitializeConnect()
{
    connect(this, &MyClass::signalToDoSomething, this, &MyClass::slotToDoSomething);
}
```

```
MyBase::MyBase(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    m_thread = new QThread();
}
void MyBase::Init()
{
    moveToThread(m_thread);
    m_thread->start();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you create your object, call `connect`, and invoke a thread? From the description I think I know what you mean, but I'd rather confirm.

Comment: @pptaszni please see my updates

Comment: What do you mean by "called in an object"? Qt only looks compares the current thread and the thread that owns the object whose slot your signal is invoking.

Comment: And where do you emit the signal? For sure from different thread than `m_thread`.

Comment: consider reading up on [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity)